# Bootstrap 4: Always display the mobile menu button no matter screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

How can I get always display the mobile menu button no matter screen size? I do not want the links to appear until a person clicks the mobile button. Thank you!

I realize there is a post here on Bootstrap 3, however it does not work with Bootstrap 4. Will you please advise?

Comment: The answer marked as duplicate is for Bootstrap 3 and the most recent answer is over a year ago. If you are in Bootstrap 4, remove the navbar-toggleable-* class from the <nav> class. Then it will always be collapsed, not just on a specific size.

Comment: Thanks. This is a useful answer, hopefully the flag gets dropped and I can upvote.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update Bootstrap 4.1.x**

Exclude the `navbar-expand*` class.

As of beta, the `navbar-toggleable-*` class was replaced with `navbar-expand-*`, but now everythings moves up a tier. Since the default state of the navbar is always collapsed/mobile (xs) you'd simply exclude the `navbar-expand-*` class so that the menu is always collapsed on all tiers.

Beta demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/HiMQd9taEd
Bootstrap 4.1.3: https://www.codeply.com/go/ugmj6XKY79

---

**Original Answer (Bootstrap 4 alpha)**

In Bootstrap 4 the navbar is very different than 3.x, and it is *always collapsed* unless overriden by one of the navbar-toggleable-* classes. You just need to make sure your navbar doesn't include `navbar-toggleable-*`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Wow</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Alpha demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/LN6szcJO53

Comment: Note that if you are copying from the Bootstrap examples you also need to delete the d-sm-inline-flex on the navbar-collapse div